# What is the word for the dirty substance on the skin of a person who hasn't been showered for days?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

If we don't shower for several day, we have some dirty things on our skin.

And when we rub the skin, we can roll this thing into a tiny ball which is dirty and as small as a grain of rice.

Is that thing called "**dirt**"?

For example, *he hasn't been showering for days, there is dirt on his skin*

Comment: I suppose the substance you describe would be mainly dead skin cells, but I've never seen any specific reference to it in English. We would just describe the person as _unwashed, needing a bath_ or similar.

Comment: My mother used to say I was 'grubby' or 'grimy' if I came indoors after playing outside all day, and tell me to wash the 'grime' off. This word is also used to describe the material accumulated by workers in dirty jobs, e.g. involving coal. Also refraining from washing for several days would lead to the skin collecting dust, pollen, etc, from the air and clothes. I believe this could also be called 'grime'.